# How to count meeting two condition in the same columns?

Tags: tableau-api

```
name Term

a    10

a    20

b    10

c    20

g    10

e    20

e    10
```

I want to count how many name has both Term 10 and Term 20 , for instance , a has both 10 & 20

so I want to count that as 1. e has both 10& 20 so I want to count that as well. but others that contains only 10 or only 20 I don't want to count them

How can I do this in tableau?

Answer (score 2):

Use an LOD Boolean to check if each [Name] has a 10 and a 20 and count the TRUEs.

```
count(if {fixed [Name] : Max([Term]=10)} and {fixed [Name] : Max([Term]=20)} then 1 end)
```

Comment: good answer. You can save typing a handful of characters with the equivalent expression sum({fixed [Name] : int(max([Term]=10) and max([Term]=20))}) -- which just combines the two fixed expressions